# AD FS Proxy (WAP) Event ID 222

Tags: authentication, proxy, timeout, adfs3.0

We're configuring an external monitor to verify our ADFS login experience.  The service will go through an end-to-end login with an account to simulate an actual SP initiated login.  The service works, but not consistently.  We will go through periods when it times out, and I see the following errors in the AD FS Proxy event logs:

```
Event ID: 222
The federation server proxy was unable to complete a request to the 
Federation Service at address '<login URL with query string>' because 
of a time-out. This might mean that the Federation Service is currently 
unavailable.

User Action
Verify that the Federation Service is running.
```

Besides the service failures, we do receive occasional reports from end users that login page loads before and after entering credentials will hang.  That's actually why we're attempting to implement a synthetic login monitor.  We do not see any errors/issues with authentication on our internal network (bypassing the proxy).

The two AD FS Proxy servers point directly to the AD FS servers using hosts file entries.  They are all on the same subnet.  There are no transport errors that I can see in netmon captures.  The AD FS service is running on all hosts.  Restarting the service does not resolve the issue, even temporarily.  ExtranetLockoutEnabled is set to false.  The account being used for the monitor is not disabled/locked in Active Directory.  There are no 230 events to indicate throttling on the proxy, but I increased those thresholds just in case - no luck.

Is there anything else on the AD FS server that would throttle or block connection attempts from the proxy servers?

Comment: Is it related to ADFS proxy congestion setting? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/927ad6c2-07d0-4d84-9e2e-a7457b75ab21/adfs-30-proxy-congestion-event-id-222?forum=ADFS